# I can't type in input text using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, onchange

i can't change text when typing in input text !
This is my fontend code :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        items: [],
        acc_email: '',
        acc_nom: '',
        acc_prenom: '',
        acc_tel: '',
    };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this); 
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

**the value of input comes from DB using fetch   :**

```
 componentDidMount(){
        const token =  localStorage.getItem('toktok');
        fetch(`${API}/api/account`,{
            method: 'GET',
            headers :{
                'authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, 
            }
        })

        .then(results => {
            return results.json();
        })

        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ items: data.result });
            console.log("account: ",data.result);
            // localStorage.setItem('mymy',  "fiss");
            // console.log(items);
            // console.log(items.length); 

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("erroooor : ",err);
        });    
    }
```

i don't know what's wrong in this function :

```
handleInputChange = e => { 
       const name = e.target.name;
       const value = e.target.value;
       this.setState({[name]: value});
       this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}
```

and finally, this's the render() that conains all inputs:

```
<div key={items._id}>
     <input type="text" value={items.email} name="acc_email"  onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
     <input type="text" value={items.nom} name="acc_nom"  onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
     <input type="text" value={items.prenom} name="acc_prenom"  onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
     <input type="text" value={items.tel}  name="acc_tel" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
     <a className="admin-btn-update" href={`/updateaccount/${items._id}`}>Modifier</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @mitsu, what's `items` inside your render method?

Comment: this is items  ```var { items} = this.state;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `value` to `defaultValue` as follows.

```js
<input type="text" defaultValue={items.email} name="acc_email"  onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly setting the values of the inputs to be `items.email`, `items.nom`.. which makes them [controlled inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), which basically means that it's the component responsibility to control what happens to those inputs.

Since you already implemented the part that updates the component `state`, all you need to do is to make the inputs values reflect this state:

```
 <input type="text" value={this.state.acc_email} name="acc_email"  onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
 <input type="text" value={this.state.acc_nom} name="acc_nom"  onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
 <input type="text" value={this.state.acc_prenom} name="acc_prenom"  onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
 <input type="text" value={this.state.acc_tel}  name="acc_tel" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

Comment: At what point you get the values from the DB? can you share that part of the code ? also `items` is an array so `items.email`, `items.nom` .. will be undefined anyway

Comment: i have a fetch in componentDidMount() that show infos in input

Comment: In addition to my solution, you need to set the state to those values you get from the DB